# Unwanted variable release (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, dealloc

I have `UIViewController` with `strong` `DataController` containing and managing a list of items (`itemsList`). In the initialization method of the latter, I read items from a file, get additional information for each of these via web services (and `ASIHTTPRequest`) and put the items in a list which is then assigned to the `itemsList` property.

With synchronous requests everything works fine but I need an asynchronous implementation. I did it and now my items get deallocated (the data controller not), following the delegates for the requests etc disappear as well. How can I keep the items alive?

**In my data controller:**

```
-(id)initDataController
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    NSMutableArray *myList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Read items from file ...

    for (NSString *itemName in items) {
        MyItem *item = [[MyItem alloc] initWithParam:itemName];
        // Here the item has already been deallocated?!
        if (item) {
            [myList addObject:item];
        }
    }
    _itemsList = myList;
    return self;
}
return nil;
}
```

In `MyItem` class there is just standard request to the server and initialization. I think the problem should be in some missing `strong/retain` but I have no idea where I should put it.

**EDIT:**

The definition of the list:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *itemsList;`

What I am wondering is that the items are `nil` even before I can put them into the list... So I tried making the property `strong` instead of `copy` but nothing changes.

Comment: Please add how the ivar _itemsList is defined to the question

Comment: You can't make an asynchronous call from in 'init' methods if the response data is required to complete the initialisation...

Comment: "Here the item has already been deallocated?!" No, they can't be, but they could be nil. Have you logged item here? It's not clear where your for loop is in relation to your asynchronous call. From what you've posted, it looks like that loop would run immediately on init'ing the data controller, not after the asynchronous method comes back with results.

Comment: Thank you all! The answer of @Wain is the perfect one, I separated the initialization and the calls to the server and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyItem *item = ...
```

This local variable forms a strong reference. If `initWithParam:` returns an object (not nil), there'w no way it can be deallocated before being added to the list (which creates another strong reference).

Please take note that your property declaration is flawed:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *itemsList;
```

The `copy` attribute does not go well with a mutable object type: When the property is assigned, the synthesized setter calls `copy` on it, which creates an **immutable** copy of the array and assigns that. This contradicts the type of the property.

Here's in fact a nice opportunity for another helpful clang compiler warning: Properties cannot be declared `copy` when their type conforms to `NSMutableCopying`. clang team, are you hearing?.

Comment: Thank you a lot. After reading your answer, I realized that actually I don't return anything in the init method, the item is deallocated before I go out of the method. So @Wain has posted in the comment to my question the perfect answer. However, could you tell me which attributes I should use for the array? `nonatomic, strong`? Or something else?